# How to make TScrollingWinControl scroll

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a custom component (TScrollingWinControl).  But the scroll bars never appare, how do you show scroll bars on this component? Do you have to create a procedure to read them in or are they all ready there?

Comment: Have a look at the source of `TScrollBox` it should give you all hints you need for your component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You give a `Range` that is longer than the control's client width/height. To scroll, you can set its position. Eg:

```
HorzScrollBar.Range := ClientWidth * 2;
HorzScrollBar.Position := HorzScrollBar.Range - ClientWidth;
```